# Is it possible to register parathread with compact.compressed wasm file

Tags: parachain, runtime, wasm

In official guides they use wasm built with `export-genesis-wasm` command to register a parathread/parachain:

- https://youtu.be/BaWcQxKRFmM?t=134
- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/

But, as I know, we can use compact.compressed wasm for runtime upgrades.

So I have two questions:

1. Can we upload compact.compressed wasm when registering a parathread to descrease reserved fee?
2. What is the difference between this genesis-wasm and wasm artifacts that we get after runtime compilation?